# 2 вопроса насчёт употребления слова и абзаца.

Tags: выбор-слов

Как правильно сказать?

*Человечность - это качество человека, ХАРАКТЕРИЗУЮЩЕЕ (или ХАРАКТЕРИЗУЮЩЕЕСЯ) высокие моральные приципы (высокими моральными принципами).*

Правильно ли выделены абзацы? Волнует вопрос, правильно ли, что "чтобы это доказать, во-первых, обратимся к тексту" относится ко второму абзацу? Или его надо в конец первого?

*"По моему мнению, человечность - это качество человека, характеризующее высокие моральные принципы. Она проявляется в добрых поступках, направленных на помощь другому существу.
(КРАСНАЯ СТРОКА) Чтобы это доказать, во-первых, обратимся к тексту. В предложениях 17-22 ребята решили спасти гусей. Они набросали досок и поползли к припаю, чтобы помочь им. Мальчики в данной ситуации проявили свою человечность."*

Answer (score 2):

Редактирование и замечания по тексту:

Человечность – это качество человека, **характеризующееся**  высокими моральными принципами.

**Что здесь плохо?** Человечность определяется через моральные принципы, которые также требуют расшифровки, поэтому они лишние. Повтор однокоренных слов:  человечность, человека. Очень короткое определение для такого сложного понятия, как человечность.

**Что делать?** Лучше всего поискать в Интернете определения для этих слов и из них составить нечто несложное и понятное всем, но в то же время правильно раскрывающее содержание термина. Что-нибудь добавить от себя, желательно простое и эмоциональное.

Обратимся к определениям.

**Челове́чность** — гуманизм, гуманность, человеческое отношение к окружающим. В общем смысле — система нравственных и социальных установок, предполагающая необходимость проявления сочувствия к людям, оказания помощи, не причинения страданий.

**НРАВСТВЕННОСТЬ**,  1. Внутренние (духовные и душевные) качества человека, основанные на идеалах добра, справедливости, долга, чести и т.п., которые проявляются в отношении к людям и природе.

**И вот что получилось:**

По моему мнению, человечность – это нравственное качество, которое проявляется в добром и справедливом отношении к природе и людям, в стремлении помочь тем, кто в этом нуждается. Совершая добрые поступки, человек проявляет своё уважение к окружающему миру, свою способность высоко ценить жизнь и защищать всё живое.

Каждый из нас может попасть в такую ситуацию, когда будет нужна наша помощь, как, например, в приведенном тексте (описание ситуации).

Ребята решили спасти гусей (предложения 17-22).  Они набросали досок и поползли к припаю (неподвижный лед, образующийся вдоль берега), чтобы помочь им. Мальчики в данном случае проявили свою человечность.

Comment: Голосую за этот ответ, но с некоторыми замечаниями. (1) "Они набросали досок и поползли к припаю, чтобы помочь им". Помочь доскам? (2) "Предложения 17-22".  Интервал обозначается с помощью тире, а дефис означает "примерно" ("человек 10-12").

Comment: (3) Человечность проявилась не в остроумном техническом решении (набросали досок и поползли), а в том, что спасали гусей с риском для собственной жизни.

Comment: Да, правильные замечания, но я всей истории не знаю и поэтому вторую часть не редактировала.

Answer (score 0):

На оба вопроса ответ один. Однозначных инструкций тут нет. Всё зависит от авторского понимания. Но рекомендации дать можно.

~1. Оба варианта приемлемы. Но смысл разный.

Я полагаю, что автор хотел сказать это.
***Человечность - это качество человека, ХАРАКТЕРИЗУЮЩЕЕСЯ  высокими моральными принципами.***
Скорее все-таки принципы характеризует качества человека, не наоборот.

~2. По смыслу это предложение начинает новый абзац, а не завершает предыдущий. 
Если есть "во-первых", то его раскрытие логично делать в том же абзаце.

***По моему мнению, человечность - это качество человека, характеризующее высокие моральные принципы. Она проявляется в добрых поступках, направленных на помощь другому существу.  ***

***Чтобы это доказать, во-первых, обратимся к тексту. В предложениях 17-22 ребята решили спасти гусей. Они набросали досок и поползли к припаю, чтобы помочь им. Мальчики в данной ситуации проявили свою человечность."***

Но это опять-таки отчасти на усмотрение автора, потому что начинать абзац с "чтобы" тоже не лучшая идея, если автор не очень понимает, зачем это ему.